# Ridge Regression accuracy in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, predict, glmnet

I have been stuck on this for some time, and am in need of some help.  I am new to R and have never done Ridge Regression using `GLMNET`.  I am trying to learn ML via the MNIST-fashion dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/zalando-research/fashionmnist).  The streamline the training (to make sure it works before I attempt to train on the full dataset, I take a stratified random sample (which produces a training dataset of 60 - 6 observations per label):

```
MNIST.sample.train = sample.split(MNIST.train$label, SplitRatio=0.001)
sample.train = MNIST.train[MNIST.sample.train,]
```

Next, I attempt to run ridge regression, using `alpha=1`...

```
x=model.matrix(label ~ . ,data=sample.train)
y=sample.train$label
rr.m <- glmnet(x,y,alpha=1, family="multinomial")
```

This seems to work.  However, when I attempt to run the prediction, I get an error:

> Error in cbind2(1, newx) %*% (nbeta[[i]]) :    not-yet-implemented
>   method for  %*% :

```
predict.rr.m <- predict(rr.m, MNIST.test, type = "class")
```

Ultimately, I am looking to obtain a single measure of the accuracy of the ridge regression.  I believe that to do so, I must first obtain a prediction.

Any thoughts on how to fix my code would be greatly appreciated.

Kevin

Comment: `label` is conceptually a factor variable. Ridge regression is the wrong approach for such data since it is for a continuous dependent variable.

Comment: Roland, that would explain it...I guess I should have looked into this before attempting RR using GLMNET.  Does the same hold for LASSO Regression using GLMNET (glmnet with alpha=0)?

Comment: I'm not an expert for this, but I believe you can use Ridge or LASSO regression only for continuous or ordinal dependent variables. A quick check with google indicates that `label` encodes fashion labels which appear to be neither.

Comment: @Roland This is not the case; from the [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf): "For
`family="multinomial"`
, [`y`] can be a
nc>=2
level factor".

Comment: @desertnaut Thanks, I stand corrected.

Comment: @desertnaut, thanks...since RR can be done with multinomial...how do I fix my problem?